# How to show $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k-2\sqrt{k}}=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Can we say that $k$ grows faster than $\sqrt{k}$ when term is large? But what is the formal way write it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, for all positive integer $k$,
$$\frac{1}{k-2\sqrt{k}}=\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{1-2\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k}}=\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{1-2\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}$$

Thus, if you know that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k}=0\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=0,$$
then you can conclude that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k-2\sqrt{k}}=\frac{0}{1-2\cdot 0}=0$$

Answer (score 5):

You can factor a $\sqrt{k}$ out of the bottom to get:
$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(\sqrt{k}-2)}$.
Now it should be clear that the bottom goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

We can restrict $k > 4$, then it suffices to show that
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} (k - 2\sqrt{k}) = \infty
$$
Using the fact that $2\sqrt{k} \in o(k)$,
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} (k - 2\sqrt{k}) = \lim_{k \to \infty} k = \infty
$$

Comment: But how do you know $ \lim_{k \to \infty} (k - 2\sqrt{k}) = \infty$?

Comment: @CoolKid I have shown it in the second step.